# Add a custom checkout field value to customer order notes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

**In short:**

1. I want to display a new field on Woocommerce Checkout 'daypart'. This is a dropdown field with 3 options.
2. The code is working and I can see it on WooCommerce backend but I need to save the data in "Customer Notes" field but as an addition of the customer comments (if any) I'm stuck here, no clue in how to do this.

**Additional information:**

I need to save daypart in a core checkout field because the store synchs to another shipping service that doesn't synch order meta data.

**Here's the code:**

```php
//define current user status to display things on checkout
if( current_user_can( 'rethunk_retailers' ) ){
  // Retailers text
    //* Add select field to the checkout page
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'wps_add_select_checkout_field');
function wps_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<h2>'.__('Partial Shipment Options').'</h2>';
    echo '<p>'.__('Option 1: details for option 1').'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.__('Option 2: details for option 2').'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.__('Option 3: details for option 3').'</p>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
        'label'         => __( 'Delivery options' ),
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
        'required' => true,
        'options'       => array(
            'blank'     => __( 'Please choose one', 'wps' ),
            'Yes I want Partial Shipment'   => __( 'Option 1: I want a partial shipment', 'wps' ),
            'Please do not ship a partiel shipment' => __( 'Option 2: Do not ship a partial shipment to me.', 'wps' ),
            'I will Wait do not refund anything'    => __( 'Option 3: Do not refund anything', 'wps' )
        )
),
        $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));

}

    //* Process the checkout
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wps_select_checkout_field_process');
 function wps_select_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ($_POST['daypart'] == "blank")
     wc_add_notice( '<strong>Please select a Partial Shipment Option </strong>', 'error' );

 }

    //* Update the order meta with field value
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
 function wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

   if ($_POST['daypart']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'daypart', esc_attr($_POST['daypart']));
 }

} else {
   // not retailers text
}
//* Add selection field value to emails
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'wps_select_order_meta_keys');
function wps_select_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {

    $keys['Shipping Option:'] = 'daypart';
    return $keys;

}
//* Display field value on the order edition page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'wps_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function wps_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){

    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery option').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'daypart', true ) . '</p>';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the "daypart" selected value to customer order notes, you will replace from your code:

```
// Update the order meta with field value
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if ( $_POST['daypart']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'daypart', esc_attr($_POST['daypart']));
}
```

by the following:

```
// Update the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'wps_update_order_meta', 20, 2 );
function wps_update_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['daypart']) && ! empty($_POST['daypart']) ) {
        // Add "daypart" selected value as custom order meta data
        $order->update_meta_data('daypart', esc_attr($_POST['daypart']));

        // Get customer note
        $customer_note = isset( $data['order_comments'] ) ? $data['order_comments'] . ' ' : '' );

        // add to existing customer note the "daypart" selected value
        $order->set_customer_note( $customer_note . esc_attr($_POST['daypart']) );
    }
}
```